# CoreData: Not null property should be optional?

Tags: swift

I'm not sure about best practice of Swift and CoreData. Do you think that not null property should be optional basically?

for example

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Item: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var itemId: String // Not null property
    @NSManaged var itemPrice: String? // null is possible
}
```

I wonder that I should notify to other programmers which property is not-null or not.

I would like to know what do you do usually. This question sound an opinion-based but I'm sure how dealing the optional is helpful for others.

FYI I found similar question

[CoreData - Setting a property of entity to be not null - Should the attribute be set as Optional or Mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549443/coredata-setting-a-property-of-entity-to-be-not-null-should-the-attribute-be)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift + CoreData: Cannot Automatically Set Optional Attribute On Generated NSManagedObject Subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485273/swift-coredata-cannot-automatically-set-optional-attribute-on-generated-nsman)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW6 .. it is clearly mentioned - You can specify that an attribute is optional—that is, it is not required to have a value. In general, however, you are discouraged from doing so—especially for numeric values (typically you can get better results using a mandatory attribute with a default value—in the model—of 0)

Comment: Thank you so much. All right, I will set optional for null-possible properties in general and I will set default value if I need it.

Comment: @zono if answer is suitable then make it accepted answer so that it can be useful for other .